# pgfplots - legend entries not recognised as array when passed as a defined variable through keyval

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I am plotting a graph in pgfplots, and would like the legend entries to be passed as a defined variable. In the code below, the first example does this, but does not work (all entries come through on one line). The code works instead if I pass the legend entries directly - how can I get the first example to work?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\def\legendentries{line1,line2}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[legend entries=\legendentries]
    \addplot coordinates {(1,2) (2,4) (3,6)};
    \addplot coordinates {(1,3) (2,6) (3,9)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[legend entries={line1,line2}]
    \addplot coordinates {(1,2) (2,4) (3,6)};
    \addplot coordinates {(1,3) (2,6) (3,9)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Code output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: You not define legend entries.  The simple ways is add `\legend{line1,line2}` to axis environments. Frankly said, it is not clear what you like to achieve and what this make any benefits to drawing of diagrams.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like the legend entries to be an input so I can allow the use to declare that input so that it is used consistently throughout the document. Changing the settings would then change the plots (i.e. which columns from a set of data files to plot), and the corresponding legend entries, on multiple plots in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macro lists often need to be explicitly expanded.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\def\legendentries{line1,line2}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[legend entries/.expand once=\legendentries]
    \addplot coordinates {(1,2) (2,4) (3,6)};
    \addplot coordinates {(1,3) (2,6) (3,9)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[legend entries={line1,line2}]
    \addplot coordinates {(1,2) (2,4) (3,6)};
    \addplot coordinates {(1,3) (2,6) (3,9)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!